# htaccess 404 page redirect not working for sub directory path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
```

It will redirect to 404 page perfectly when access like `www.example.com/about` if `about` is not exists. But will not redirect to 404 page when I access `www.example.cpm/page/test`.

Actually there is page called 'page' and `www.example.cpm/page/test` not exists. It should redirect to 404 page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404-error.php
```

Comment: @anubhava I have updated question with full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 404 handler is find but problem is your rewrite rule for adding `.php` extension. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` returns true for `/page/test` even if just `/page.php` is found.

Have your rules like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404-error.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|HEAD)\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Showing error "The requested URL /GET was not found on this server." when access sub pages. pls help.

Comment: Its showing not found error.
 The requested URL /tour was not found on this server.

Comment: What is exact URL are you entering in browser? What happens when you enter `www.example.cpm/page/test`?

Comment: www.example.com/page will show the correct page, but when I hit www.example.cpm/page/test it should redirect to 404 page (as ErrorDocument 404)

Comment: Yes. www.example.com/page/test redirecting to 404 page now. But www.example.com/page also showing 404 page.

Comment: htaccess located at root (www.example.com).