# How to show custom 404 error page for the subfolder in php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing a project in which I want to show my custom error page for 404 error. The codes that I have used are working but not totally. So at first, I am showing the structure for my project then the problems I have.

My site name is `www.example.com` in which I have 4 files and a folder, files are `index.php`, `about.php`, `error.php`, `.htaccess` and folder name is `admin`.

In the `admin` folder I have lots of pages that I am loading with one single page in index.php. the URLs to access any page I am doing it with `www.example.com/admin/index.php?page=login` like this, so when page is login it shows me the login page.

Up to this everything is good, now I have used a code in .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

So after using it when I am trying to access a wrong URL such as `www.example.com/abt.php` it shows me the code written in `error.php` which is quite natural for my code.
So when I am trying to access again two wrong URLs like `www.example.com/adminindex.php?page=login` and `www.example.com/admin/inx.php?page=login` it is not showing me the code written in `error.php` rather it shows me just a message `File Not Found`.

I want that these two types of wrong URLs it should show me the code written in `error.php`.

Interestingly what I want is easily happens in localhost but not on in server.
I cannot understand why it is working perfectly fine in localhost but not on the server.
So how can I do that please help me to complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that whether it can work for you or not? But you can give it a try i think it can resolve your issue which is quite similar to the previously asked question on stack overflow [htaccess 404 page redirect not working for sub directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698277/htaccess-404-page-redirect-not-working-for-sub-directory-path/31698931#31698931)
brilliantly answered by [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava). I hope it can help you to solve the issue. Also if the above does not help you out then you can also visit this 2 links [SOLVED "File not found." instead of custom 404 file with php-fpm enabled](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/file-not-found-instead-of-custom-404-file-with-php-fpm-enabled.634101/) & [SOLVED "File not found" appears instead of 404.shtml (easy htaccess solution)](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/file-not-found-appears-instead-of-404-shtml-easy-htaccess-solution.657107/)

Comment: Thanks it did work for me but one question why the page is redirecting even it is not 404 . Actually when i inspect for wrong url like `www.example.com/adminindex.php?page=login` it didnot show me 404, but showing on `www.example.com/about.ph`

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is no good method for that without using `mod_rewrite`.
The only solution would be to put another `.htaccess` to your `/admin` subdirectory (with a valid path for your `error.php`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate it how to do.

Comment: the easiest way would be to copy your `.htaccess` file to .`/admin` direcetory and to copy your `error.php` file to `./admin` directory as well (the second step may not be needed, depends of server configuration)

Comment: Okay I am trying to do please wait

Comment: No its not working for the above mentioned two wrong URLs

Comment: are you using some proxy? rewrite rules? maybe try adding `ProxyErrorOverride on`

Comment: Nope the same result and I am not using any Proxy, Rewriterules just what I have mentioned that's it. Please check i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

in httpd.conf file (the is in AppServ\Apache24\conf directory)
put this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

if not be ok try save the file as html

Comment: Okay I am trying to do that

Comment: No I cannot find that file in server

Comment: if you using appserv find it in C:\AppServ\Apache24\conf